# Multiply out the argument of a sine function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How do I multiply out the following?
>
> $$y=3.11 \sin (2\pi/365(x-80.75))+12.19$$

I believe the equality should multiply out to

$$y=3.11 \sin(2\pi/365x-323\pi/730)+12.19\,,$$

but I am unsure how to get $-323\pi/730$ inside the sine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your belief is well-founded:

$$\frac{2\pi}{365}80.75\left(\frac{2}{2}\right)  = \frac{323\pi}{730}$$